# Manipulating non-adjacent cells in python using arrays or rec-arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I’m trying to change non-adjacent values of an array simultaneously, and it doesn’t seem to be working.  Trying the example below, the code does not break, but the values do not change.  I have run into the same problem using recarrays.  Has anyone run into this before?  Any thoughts?  For example:

```
import numpy as np

simulants = np.zeros([10, 5])

simulants[:, 4] =np.array([5,25, 10, 5, 45, 30, 60, 1, 80, 80])

simulants[simulants[:,4]==5][:,0]=np.array([1, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this worked and was informative about why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of indexing can matter. Try:

```
simulants[:,0][simulants[:,4]==5]=np.array([1,2])
```

The reason why order matters is because `simulants[:,0]` is a view, while
`simulants[simulants[:,4]==5]` is a (sub)copy of the array. (Modifying a view of an array modifies the underlying array. Modifying a copy does not.)

`simulants[:,0]` is a view because it uses [basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy-docs/reference/arrays.indexing.rst/#arrays-indexing).
`simulants[simulants[:,4]==5]` is a copy because it uses a bool ndarray which triggers [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy-docs/reference/arrays.indexing.rst/#arrays-indexing).

---

**Edit**: As @eryksun points out in the comments, the assignment could be better handled with a single index:

```
simulants[simulants[:,4]==5, 0] = np.array([1,2]
```

Comment: @eryksun: True! I've forgotten the simple solution :).